# How to block line of sight while vines grow?

Tags: fence

Our garden backs onto a playing field for a school, with a ~15 foot chainlink fence separating the two. We have some vines growing up the fence, but they will likely take a few years to grow sufficiently to block someone seeing from the field into the garden and vice versa.

While we wait for the vines to grow, is there something nice-looking we can use to block line of sight from the field to our garden? The previous owner of the house used something like bamboo fencing to do it, but when we moved in it was a) ratty and horrible looking and b) had big holes in it anyway, so we took it down.

Is there something less offensive we can put up while we wait for the vines to cover the fence? We'd need something 20-30 feet long.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what vines have you planted and what area do you live in?

Comment: We have honeysuckle, a potato vine, and a couple of others. Live in San Jose, CA.

Answer (score 2):

Try Golden Hops, Humulus lupulus 'Sunbeam'...this will cover that fence within a few months...it is beautiful, you can make beer from it and it dies back every year so you can clean up the old vines before the new ones take over...or you might have to periodically cut them to the ground, remove and allow to grow back. Plant this guy and stand back!  Keep track of your other vines but I think this plant is worth looking into for instant (almost) privacy.